# Python errors when formatting strings that came from a list of strings?

Tags: string, python-3.x, format, readlines

Given the contents of my file:

```
"ID","Name","Type 1","Type 2","Generation","Legendary"
1,"Bulbasaur","Grass","Poison",1,"FALSE"
6,"Charizard","Fire","Flying",1,"FALSE"
4,"Charmander","Fire","",1,"FALSE"
169,"Crobat","Poison","Flying",2,"FALSE"
146,"Moltres","Fire","Flying",1,"TRUE"
643,"Reshiram","Dragon","Fire",5,"TRUE"
641,"Tornadus, (Incarnate Form)","Flying","",5,"TRUE"
```

I use readlines() to create a list of each string as its own line.

Then I attempt to take those strings and format them to the following format:

```
'Bulbasaur': (1, 'Grass', 'Poison', 1, False)
```

I need to make sure the exact quotations are correct and that all lower cases and uppercases are correct. I also must ensure that the types are made into what they are needed.

When I go to iterate or format the strings (ie strip and split), I am receiving a few errors:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I am seriously confused as to how this needs to work. My overall function runs but is not returning the right results. Example: it returns charmander's info in the dictionary instead of bulbasaur's.

- I need to take the results from readlines() and get each line as a string
- I need to format that string into the format provided above
- Then once I have that format, I need to make it into a dictionary.

Here is my function which is really all over the place:

```
def read_info_file(filename): #accept file 
    file= open(filename)
    lines=file.readlines()[1:] #skip first header line
    d={}
    for line in lines:
        split_line=line.split(',') #get individual strings
        legendary=True
        if 'F' == split_line[-1].strip('"')[0]: #check last position if t or f to format legendary correctly
        legendary=False

        if len(split_line) > 6:
            (k,v)=(split_line[1]+split_line[2].strip('"'),  #puts right order and removes excess quotations
 (int(split_line[0]),split_line[3].strip('"'),split_line[4].strip('"'),
        int(split_line[5]),legendary))

        else:
            (k,v)=(split_line[1].strip('"'),
(int(split_line[0]),split_line[2].strip('"'),split_line[3].strip('"'),
            int(split_line[4]),legendary))

    d.update([(k,v)])
    file.close()
    return d
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the built-in `csv` module simplifies things:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

def read_info_file(filename):
    with open(filename,'r',newline='') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        next(r) # skip header
        d = {}
        for id,name,type1,type2,generation,legendary in r:
            d[name] = int(id),type1,type2,int(generation),legendary=='TRUE'
    return d

pprint(read_info_file('input.txt'))
```

**Output**

> ```
> {'Bulbasaur': (1, 'Grass', 'Poison', 1, False),
>  'Charizard': (6, 'Fire', 'Flying', 1, False),
>  'Charmander': (4, 'Fire', '', 1, False),
>  'Crobat': (169, 'Poison', 'Flying', 2, False),
>  'Moltres': (146, 'Fire', 'Flying', 1, True),
>  'Reshiram': (643, 'Dragon', 'Fire', 5, True),
>  'Tornadus, (Incarnate Form)': (641, 'Flying', '', 5, True)}
> ```

Comment: I wish I could do that! Unfortunately I am not allowed to use any imported modules.

Comment: @ocean.1234 Are you supposed to write a parser?  Because the last data item has a comma embedded in the quotes, so a simple `line.split(',')` won't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what a parser is?